# Ray tracing with triangle meshes in WebGL failing with 3k+ triangles

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, glsl, webgl, raytracing

I was testing the ray tracer that i wrote for some fps feedback. With meshes that are 3k+ triangles it renders for like 2 seconds correctly then the whole canvas turns into red color(red is the primary color in the scene). I post here to have a feedback about what is happening, if i have some fundamental error which i cannot understand or it is because I don't have any acceleration method(BVH, or a kd-tree) for my ray tracing path, and now i check for intersections in all the triangles. 
Smalls scenes(1-1.5k triangles) i can render them  with success so i cannot imagine what is going wrong.
I thought it would just went slower.

I post below the 2 main functions of my ray tracer in openGL ES

```
bool hitScene(Ray R_, out vec3 hitPos, out vec3 normal, out Material material, Sphere lightSource){ 

    vec4 a = vec4(0.0), b = vec4(0.0), c = vec4(0.0), aN = vec4(0.0),bN= vec4(0.0),cN= vec4(0.0);
    float mindist = 1000.;
    bool weHitSomething = false;
    vec3 hitPos1 = vec3(0.),triangleNormal = vec3(0.,0.,0.), sphereNormal, barycentricCoord;


    int alg = 2;
    if (alg == 2) {

        //here we chck all the mesh if we hit a triangle if the mesh and we keep the closest hitpoint

        for (int i = 0; i < vertsCount; i += 3) {

            a = texelFetch(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0);
            b = texelFetchOffset(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(1, 0));
            c = texelFetchOffset(uMeshData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(2, 0));

            aN = texelFetch(uNormData, ivec2(i, 0), 0);
            bN = texelFetchOffset(uNormData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(1, 0));
            cN = texelFetchOffset(uNormData, ivec2(i, 0), 0, ivec2(2, 0));

            vec3 uvt;
            vec3 intersect;
            float z;
            bool isHit = hitTriangleSecond(R_.orig, R_.dir, a.xyz, b.xyz, c.xyz, uvt, triangleNormal, intersect, z);
            if (isHit) {

                if (z<mindist && z > 0.001) {
                    hitPos1 = intersect;

                    mindist = z;
                    weHitSomething = true;
                    material.type = DIEL;
                    material.albedo = vec3(.8, .3, .4);
                    normal = normalize(aN.xyz*uvt.x + bN.xyz*uvt.y + cN.xyz*uvt.z);
                    hitPos = hitPos1;            
                }
            }      
        } 

    }

   return weHitSomething;
}

//Trace is the main function of the max bounces
vec3 Trace(out Ray ray, Sphere lightSource){

    vec3 hitPos, normal;
    bool isShpere;
    Material material;
    vec3 color = vec3(1.);
    vec3 attenuation = vec3(1.);
    vec3 light = vec3(1.,1.,1.), shadow = vec3(1.,1.,1.);

        for(int i=0; i< 3; i++){

            // we check if we hit something
            if(hitScene(ray, hitPos, normal, material, lightSource)){
                if (material.type == METAL) {
                    //we calculate the new direction
                    vec3 direction = normalize(reflect(ray.dir, normal));


                    ray = Ray(hitPos, direction); 
                    light = getLight(color, lightSource,hitPos, normal);
                    //shadow = calcShadow(lightSource, hitPos);
                    color *= material.albedo * light*shadow;
                     attenuation *= material.albedo;   
                     //color = normal *light; 
                }
                if (material.type == DIEL) {
                    //we calculate the new direction
                    vec3 direction = normalize(reflect(ray.dir, normal));

                    ray = Ray(hitPos, direction); 
                    light = getLight(color, lightSource,hitPos, normal);
                    //shadow = calcShadow(lightSource, hitPos);
                    color *= material.albedo * light*shadow;
                    attenuation *= material.albedo;   

                }
            } else {
                //color = attenuation * vec3(.2,.2, .2);
            }

        }

    return color;
}
```

I wrote a object parser to keep the triangle normal per vertex and triangle vertices in python. and then they are loaded in the hitScene() function

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730222/opengl-es-fragment-shader-apparently-impossibly-returning-white

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408908/custom-shader-material-taking-forever-to-initialize/54413753

Comment: So I need to dig deeper... Oh well..

Comment: @ThodorisKoutsis You probably need an acceleration structure, check last year's nvidia RTX launch event. Basically instead of raytracing all the triangles from all the rays you put a variety of "boxes" around different group of triangles, so that each time you select the area (box) that you hit and ignore the rest boxes (and the triangles within). The structure you need is probably the bounding volume hierarchy.